# Navigation title bar is glitchy, it shows a grey background when going back

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

This gif will help you to understand what my problem is:

[image]

At some of my navigation controllers, I have never experienced this issue before and I am having a hard time debugging this problem.

Steps to reproduce: Clone https://github.com/Jasperav/GlitchedNavigationBar or

1. Create new project
2. Embed the existing viewcontroller in a tab bar controller
3. Embed the same viewcontroller in a navigation bar controller
4. Add a new viewcontroller in the storyboard
5. On the new viewcontroller, tap **Hide Bottom Bar on Push** (This causes the problem)
6. Add a button in on the first viewcontroller which will show the new viewcontroller. Now we have the problem.

I am running Xcode 10 and swift 4.2

Comment: Presumably you're doing something unusual with your navigation bar - Subclassed? Custom background? Something else?

Comment: @AshleyMills I added a reproduction path, I am doing nothing weird I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your navigation Bar is translucent and shows part of your controller under the navigation bar. Your top controller has a map in it and when you navigate back it animates it under the navigation bar thats the cause of the flickering.

To change the translucent effect of the navigation bard only in one controller you need to add this to you viewDidLoad method:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

or if you wan to change it globally then add this to you didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the app delegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```